# zClip jQuery Plugin copy self attribute on click

Tags: jquery, zclip

I am trying to use the zClip jQuery plugin (http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/#features) and am wanting to copy an attribute of the link that is being clicked on.

Essentially I need to copy a URL to the clipboard on click, but its not working.

```
$('a.activation_copy_link').zclip({
  path: "<%= asset_path('ZeroClipboard.swf') %>",
  copy: $(this).data('link')
});
```

HTML Markup:

```
<a href="#" class="activation_copy_link" data-link="activation_url_here">Click to copy link</a>
```

I understand that the `$(this)` will refer to the zclip object and not the jQuery object, but I have tried everything I can think of and it's not working.

Comment: Can you show more markup (html)? are you trying to grab the href attribute of the anchor activation_copy_link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('a.activation_copy_link').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $(this).zclip({
  path: "<%= asset_path('ZeroClipboard.swf') %>",
  copy: $this.data('link')
});

});
```

Comment: I am now receiving this error `GET http://localhost:3000/assets/ZeroClipboard.swf 404 (Not Found)` -- The SWF file is in app/assets/flash

Comment: That is an entirely different issue with the plugin and setting it up.  Make sure you have all the paths correct and your webserver enabled to serve swf files.

Comment: By the way the path with the 404 error is different than where you've indicated the file is supposed to be.

Comment: Working with Rails > 3.0 and the asset pipeline, you can stick your asset files (swf, coffee, js, css, scss, etc) in any folder in the `app/assets` directory and it works just fine. Now the SWF file is found if the path is placed on the link itself, its just breaking if you apply the zclip after the click

Comment: Ended up fixing it with this (in application.rb): `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "flash")`

Comment: I was about to comment that I've answered your question and that it seems to be something related to the server side.. Glad you got it worked out.

Comment: Thanks! And the asset pipeline strikes again!

Comment: @dennismonsewicz Can you please mark the answer by clicking the checkmark so that future people can be helped.  Thanks!

Comment: This solved my issue of several links and other text on the page being highlighted. Seems to work in Firefox, which was the tricky browser of all of them. Thanks!